# Validar todos los input de una clase con JQuery

Tags: jquery, html5

Intento recorrer todos los input de un formulario asociado por la clase, en donde deseo validar si cada uno de estos elementos esta vacio, y si lo esta que me deshabilite un boton, cuando todos esten llenos que habilite y si es posible anexar que para todos los campos el minimo de caracteres sea de 7

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#btn-buy').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.reque').each(function(){
    alert($(this).text())
    $('.reque').keyup(function() {
      console.log($(this));
      if($(this).val() != '') {
       $('#btn-buy').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    });
 });
});

<form class="form" id="creditcard-form" role="form">
        <h1>Formulario de Pago</h1>
        <div class="jumbotron" id="wrapper">

         <h3 class="alert">Por favor ingrese los siguientes datos</h3>
         <div class="container row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label">Nombre de su organización:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg reque" name="nombre_organizacion" id="nombre_organizacion" required="" pattern="[A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0 ]{1,150}" title="Solo letras son permitidas para este campo" maxlength="150" onkeypress="return validar(event);">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label reque">Correo electrónico:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="correo_electronico" id="correo_electronico" required="" maxlength="255">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label reque">Teléfono:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="telefono" id="telefono" required="" pattern="[0-9+]{7,50}" maxlength="50" title="Solo números y el signo + son permitidos en este campo" onkeypress="return validartelf(event);">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label reque">Dirección:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="direccion" id="direccion" required="" maxlength="100" onkeypress="return validarln(event);">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label reque">País:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php 
                        require_once "includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php";
                        $sql="SELECT * FROM paises";
                        $sql=$conn->query($sql);
                        echo '<select required="" name="idpais" id="idpais" class="form-control form-control-lg">';

                        echo '  <option value="0">Seleccione</option>';

                        foreach ($sql as $key => $value) {

                            echo '  <option value="'.$value['iso'].'">'.utf8_encode($value['nombre']).'</option>';  

                        }

                        echo '</select>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label reque">Ciudad:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input required="" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" pattern="[A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0 ]{1,50}" title="Solo letras son permitidas en este campo" name="city" id="city" maxlength="50" onkeypress="return validar(event);">
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-12" id="creditcard">               

                <h3 class="alert">Información de su Tarjeta de Crédito</h3>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label reque">Nombre del títular de la tarjeta:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input required="" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" pattern="[A-Za-zñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ0 ]{1,50}" name="payer_name" title="Solo letras son permitidas en este campo" id="card-holder-name" maxlength="50" onkeypress="return validar(event);">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label reque">Número:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="credit_card_number" id="card-number" required="" maxlength="16" pattern="[0-9]{16}" title="Solo números son permitidos en este campo" onkeypress="return getCardType(event);">
                        <span id="mensaje"></span>                                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <img name="imgty" id="type" src="" alt="" width="54" height="54" style="float: left;">
                        <input type="hidden" name="payment_method" id="payment_method">                                
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-md-4 f-control-label" for="expiry-month">Fecha de expiración</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select required="" class="form-control form-control-lg reque" name="month_exp" id="expiry-month">
                                <option value="01">Ene (01)</option>
                                <option value="02">Feb (02)</option>
                                <option value="03">Mar (03)</option>
                                <option value="04">Abr (04)</option>
                                <option value="05">May (05)</option>
                                <option value="06">Jun (06)</option>
                                <option value="07">Jul (07)</option>
                                <option value="08">Ago (08)</option>
                                <option value="09">Sep (09)</option>
                                <option value="10">Oct (10)</option>
                                <option value="11">Nov (11)</option>
                                <option value="12">Dic (12)</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select required="" class="form-control form-control-lg reque" name="year_exp">
                                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> CCV:</a></label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input required="" type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg reque" name="security_code" id="cvv" maxlength="4" pattern="[0-9]{3,4}" title="Solo números son permitidos en este campo" onkeypress="return validarcvv(event);">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label">Documento de identidad:</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input required="" type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg reque" pattern="[0-9]{25}" title="Solo números son permitidos en este campo" name="number_document" id="number_document" maxlength="25" onkeypress="return validarnum(event);">
                </div>
            </div>

            <h3 class="alert text-center">Por favor ingrese el ID del vendedor</h3>

            <div class="form-group row">

                <label for="" class="col-md-4 form-control-label">ID del vendedor:</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" title="Solo letras son permitidas en este campo" name="id_seller" id="id_seller" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return validarln(event);">
                </div>
            </div> 

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">

            <div class="">

                <br>
                <?php $deviceSessionId = md5(session_id().microtime()); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="dsi" value="<?php echo $deviceSessionId; ?>">
                <button id="btn-buy" onclick="Payment.creditcard()" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Pagar ahora</button>
            </div>

            <a href="https://www.payulatam.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/logo-payu.png" alt="PayU Latam" border="0" /></a> <br>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="politicas de tratamiento de datos.p" target="_blank"><img src="img/pdf.png" alt=""> Política de Tratamiento de seguridad de la Información para dar cumplimiento a la 1581 de 2012 </a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pues deberia ser haci , no has puesto tu codigo html y no dices que error te aparece en tu pregunta.

tienes que agregar en **validarCamposVacios** `class="form-control form-control-lg validarCamposVacios"`a los input que quieras aplicar esta funcion.

```
    $('.validarCamposVacios').change(function(){
        $(this).each(function(){
        var campos = $(this).val();
        if (campos==="" || campos<=7){
           $('#btn-buy').hide();
       }else{
          $('#btn-buy').show();
         }
        });
      });
```

nota: podrias usar tambien `$('#btn-buy').hide();` para ocultarlo

Comment: Que pasa con tu codigo si todos los inputs estan vacios, pero el ultimo no?

Comment: no te entiendo ¿si todos estan vacios pero el ultimo no? ¿como puede ser eso?

Comment: Perdon, me refiero a que todos esten vacios excepto el ultimo.

Comment: Todos los campos son requeridos, menos el ultimo, ID de vendedor

Comment: si  ID de vendedor no ocupa esa funcion no le agregues la clase validarCampos

Comment: Igual no funciona, ademas la funcion hide(), show() son para ocultar y mostrar no para habilitar y deshabilitar

Comment: El boton sigue habilitandose al completar un campo nada mas

Comment: pero que error no te funciona ? ¿ya hciciste console.log()? no has dicho que esta mal

Comment: El codigo si funciona, solo que al completar un campo ya me habilita el boton, tendria que esta deshabilitado hasta que todos los input esten completados

Comment: No se como hacerlo @CarlosEnriqueGilGil

Answer (score 0):

Una solución asumiendo que los inputs requeridos son los que tienen la clase `.reque`. La función `existenRequeridosVacios` retorna `true` si existe algún campo requerido vacío. El evento se lanza cada vez que se modifica cualquier valor del formulario, sea requerido o no requerido.

```javascript
function existenRequeridosVacios() {
  let requeridosVacios = false;
  $('.reque').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
      requeridosVacios = true;
      return;
    }
  });
  return requeridosVacios;
}

$("#creditcard-form :input").change(function () {
  $("#btn-buy").prop("disabled", existenRequeridosVacios());
});
```